Examples for different cases of the global existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs
I have a question regarding the global existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations (ODEs) for Lipschitz continuous functions.
$f \in L(J \times D,E)$ with (L meaning Lipschitz continous). Then for every $(t_0, x_0) \in J\times D$ there exists a unique nonextendible solution $u(\cdot, t_0, x_0) \colon J(t_0, x_0) \to D$ of the IVP.
I am looking for examples for the following case 3:

Case 1: The solution u is defined on the entire interval  J   $ f: J \times D \to E \ , u' = f $ (means $t^+=sup$ J).
Case 2: The solution u tends to infinity and is therefore not defined on the entire interval ( J ).
Case 3: The solution u approaches the boundary of  D , that is, $\lim_{t \to t^+} dist(u(t), \partial D) = 0$.

I have examples for Cases 1 and 2, but I am struggling to find an example for Case 3.

Here is a rather artificial example, but one that captures the phenomenon of Case 3.  Let $D = (-1,1)$ and consider the IVP $x'(t) =1$ with $x(0) = 0$.  The solution is clearly the smooth function $x : J \to D$, with $J = D$, given by
$x(t) = t$.  Note that $x(t) \to \pm 1 \in \partial D$ as $t \to \pm 1$ in $J$.
